# how to delete terraform resources in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, terraform-provider-aws

I create resources through gitlab, but I can't delete them. At the beginning, I output the plan to artifacts to apply it in apply. Then resources are created and after creation I want to delete them. But it does not work to delete them, it is impossible to output them to out in the same way as the plan, and if I just type destroy, as in the terminal, that the job is running successfully, but 0 resources is deleted. My.gitlab-ci.yaml is like this

```
stages:
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply
  - destroy

before_script:
  - rm -rf .terraform
  - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY  
  - terraform init

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:    
    - terraform validate
  tags:
    - shell-runner

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - validate
  artifacts:
    paths:      
      - "planfile"      
  tags:
    - shell-runner
      
apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - terraform apply -input=false -auto-approve   
  dependencies:
     - plan
  tags:
    - shell-runner
  when: manual

destroy:
  stage: destroy
  script:
    - terraform destroy -state="planfile" -auto-approve
  tags:
    - shell-runner
  when: manual
```

Comment: The usage for the Terraform commands is incorrect. You should check the documentation for the Terraform CLI and fix them, and then you will have your expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one of the solutions + can be done via s3 bucket
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/terraform_state.html

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing [Terraform state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/index.html) with [Terraform plan](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/plan.html#planning-options).

Terraform state is a centralized file for storing information about all your infrastructure.

Terraform plan is an ephemeral file with planned changes only.

Please set up [Terraform state location](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/index.html#available-backends) correctly and do not set the plan file as a state file while destroying. You need any backend type but `local`.

Comment: you mean do this? script:
    - terraform destroy -state="terraform.tfstate" -auto-approve

Comment: You do not have to pass -state parameter (terraform.state is its default value btw). When you set up a remote backend, this will work automatically. The local backend does not work with Gilab CI (and any other CI) because every job runs in a clean environment. Shell executor makes this even worse.

Comment: if I understood you correctly, then you need to write terraform destroy -auto-approve, since this is done on a remote server, it should trigger and delete resources. But in fact, I also tried it. And also removes 0 resources. Maybe I'm very stupid, but if you can write what exactly you need to prescribe so that it is deleted, then I would be able to carry out my logical chain to the end

Answer (score 0):

```
stages:
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
before_script:
  - export HCLOUD_TOKEN=${HCLOUD_TOKEN}
  - rm -rf .terraform
  - terraform --version
  - terraform init

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out "planfile" --var-file=secret.tfvars
  dependencies:
    - validate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - planfile

apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - terraform apply -input=false "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - plan
  when: manual

destroy:
  stage: destroy
  script:
    - terraform init
    - terraform destroy -auto-approve
  when: manual
  dependencies: 
    - apply
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).